# Execute Python Script from Django

Tags: python, django, subprocess, popen, django-celery

I am trying to execute a python script from a webpage through a Django view. Other questions related to a known script from within the Django project directory. I need to be able to execute a script anywhere on the system given the file path. Eventually, multiple scripts will be run in parallel using Celery or a similar method. Should I be using some permutation of popen or sub-processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Celery.

`subprocess`, `multiprocessing`, and `threading` all are powerful tools, but are in general  hard to get working. They're more useful if you already have a working system, are running at the limit of the hardware, and don't mind spending a **good deal** of effort to get lower latency or parallel processing or higher throughput.

Comment: I'm very new to this so I'm just trying to get a single script execution to work for now. How would I call my .py file and execute it using Celery? I currently have: subprocess.call(file path) in a view and a button on my webpage I would like to execute the command.

Comment: I haven't used Celery, but I suggest `print(subprocess.check_output(<mycommand>))` -- it returns the program's output as a byte string, and raises an error if something goes wrong.

Comment: It turned out to be fairly straight forward. I just used subprocess.popen(). The logic between django, celery, and html for checking things was a mess though.

Comment: @JasonHawkins if you'd like multiple `Popen`s at once try this snippet: http://pastebin.com/fCPU5asA